# About Element Level Security Feature

Tags: security, marklogic

Can we use element level security feature to protect
particular triple data set(or part of triple, such as only "Objectives")?
I would like to know answer for both managed and unmanaged triples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/element#id_73454)

> Element level security is not implemented for the triple index. However in some scenarios, where the document's security is stronger than the element security on a triple, the protected triple will be added to the triple index. This is because the document's security already covers the protected element. The information contained in the triple is therefore protected at the document level.
>
> Query operations that rely on the triple index (such as SPARQL, SQL, the new version of MarkLogic ODBC, and the Optic API) are not supported by element level security. For content that makes use of the triple index (like semantics and SQL) if a document contains protected elements and the element level security is stronger than the document level security, the query will not return any results.

In short, element level security is not supported by the triple index. Don't use it on triples. However, if you use it, and document security is stronger, you will see triples returned. If you use it and element security is stronger, you will see no triples returned. For more information on how MarkLogic determines if element or document level security is stronger, [see the documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/element#id_12016). But seriously, don't apply element level security to triples so you don't find yourself debugging these nuances.

Comment: So to control access to single triple set(managed triple), do you prefer to use document level security?

Comment: For example, in case there is a single triple data represents "fact", how to hide this single triple data set from certain role/user?

Comment: @Njbs per my understanding that single triple must be in a document with the correct permissions on its own in an unmanaged scenario or inserted with the correct permissions in a managed scenario.